# React build with parcel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration, package, parcel

I started using Parcel (together with React), and when I build a project, in the file "index.html " links start with "/", and should be with "./", who knows how to configure?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the CLI, Parcel has a parameter [`--public-url`](https://en.parceljs.org/cli.html#set-the-public-url-to-serve-on), which you can use to change `/` to `./`:

So your build script might look something like: `npx parcel build index.html --public-url ./`